# IIS on Local Machine Not Saving Session State

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, iis, session-variables, iis-8

I currently have a local instance of IIS on my development machine with which I am working on development of an ASP.NET MVC application. I have IIS8, and currently the site loads, everything seems to be working fine except for session state.

When stepping through my code (all of which works fine on our demo server - so I know it's not the code), it seems the session variables are set without any exceptions being thrown. However, **any time I attempt to access one of those variables, the value is returned as an empty string ("").** I have checked what I know to look for in web.config, as well as settings in IIS with no luck. My Web.Config sessionState settings look like this:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="240" />
```

I have tried adding other settings in here like cookieless, etc... However I haven't had any luck. I have also played with settings in IIS, current settings are in this screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/Vny4uUqMleB

**EDIT: Adding some of the session state code for reference. Note that this system is written in VB despite my efforts to get them to switch to C# :(**

Firstly, this would be an example of it being set - we have a class for managing state (session, cookie, app, etc). both "key" and "value" are string variables passed in.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session(key) = value
```

And when reading the value, same situation, the code is wrapped in a class for managing state, but this would be the important line:

```
  //Read value from session state
  If Not (HttpContext.Current.Session(key) Is Nothing) Then
    strValue = HttpContext.Current.Session(key).ToString()
  End If
```

If anyone can give me some guidance on what to look at next, what things could potentially be affecting it, or really any clues whatsoever, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: To answer we'll need some sample code showing how you set & retrieve a Session value.

Comment: Give me a moment and I'll edit my post. Thanks!

Comment: All set, if you need to see full definitions of the state functions I can add those, but it's 99% just decision making code, and I HAVE verified that the lines in question are the lines getting hit during execution.

Comment: Code seems OK. Now for a bigger task: go here and check/do everything it says... https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/asp/session

Comment: On it - might take me a little while as I'm working on other things simultaneously at the moment, but I will report back when I'm done. Thank you!

Comment: And just to be sure: double check that your `Function` ends with `Return strValue`.

Comment: Since this is on my local machine, which is running Windows 8 (and not a server OS), will I need to do anything differently? I just noticed it's telling me to go in to server manager, which I don't currently have on this machine. I'll still go through it and do what's available on my machine, but just a note that I am on my dev machine, and connecting to localhost (or my IP/website)

Comment: Yup, it does - these functions work fine on our demo server, so that SHOULD mean that the code is good to go, as the statemanagement class hasnt changed in some time. Either way, I'll look through the link you sent and give our code a once-over one more time to be sure.

Comment: @PeterB- that article did it! I had to install some more things in IIS, specifically the ASP options. I had installed all the ASP.NET libs but the ASP lib was apparently needed to handle session state. After installation and checking to be sure things were configured right, session issues went away. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

All credit to Peter B in the comments to the main post. He sent me to this link https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/asp/session

Specifically, the portion forcing you to install the ASP libs after things are set up is what fixed it for me. Went to the ASP icon in IIS, made sure that session was set up, restarted debug, and all my session issues went away.