# ASP Session Variable Clearing When Returning From External Site

Tags: asp.net, session

I have an asp.net application, version 4.5.2, that we have to leave our site to go to a payment site and then it returns after the transaction.  We use session variables to maintain the user id and that is used on the return to complete the transaction on our side in the db.  Everything was working well until last month on return from the payment site, the session variables are cleared.  I have 3 dev machines and the behavior happens on all of them now.

The strange thing is that on the production server I setup a test website, using identical code I am having issues with, and it works like a charm.  I have made no IIS changes, web.config, etc that I could see as that start of my issues.

If I cancel out of the payment process, it is able to redirect back to my website and the session variables maintain.

I would like to blame the payment folks for making a change, but with it working when hosted on a server I really cant do that :)

Is it possible for the payment site to trigger a new session when it detects a redirect to a local host?  I have read several forums and checked my timeout settings, cookie settings, etc, but again I have made no changes to IIS or web.config from when it was working.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What is your exact (programming) question?

Comment: @BrianYutz What's different between your `dev` machines and the `production` server? That's where I'd look. Did you update the dev machines in a way which was not applied to your production server? Specifically, about a month ago since that is when you say the problem started. Did a setting in `IIS` on the dev machines get changed which was not changed on `production`? Have you looked at this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40345043/iis-on-local-machine-not-saving-session-state)?

Comment: The production server now is Windows Server 2016.  We migrated from server 2008 a few weeks ago.  The old production server ran well with no issues, so I actually fired it back up to see what behavior it would display.  It now has the same issues as all my local machines.  I know for a fact that when it was shutdown it worked with no issues, and no changes were made prior to decommissioning.

Comment: @RyanWilson I looked at the link you posted and no luck!  Thank you for the suggestion though.  I did not update dev machines in any way that the prod wasn't.  The failure literally happened over a weekend when no changes were made.